# Jquery close div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I am trying to place an Ad using `<iframe>` or `<script>` tags inside my `DIV` when users click on the `DIV` it automatically removes that `DIV` which contains ads in it. My code works 100% fine when I load an image in that `DIV` but when I put `<iframe>` or `<script>` tags which loads ad content it won't remove the div. I don't know why? is there any function that automatically detects the click on `DIV` function and remove it?

Here is the live working example https://jsfiddle.net/infohassan/uvzjj9h4/2/

Here is my HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.custom_closebtn').click(function() {
    $('.custom_ads_placement').remove();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.custom_adContent').click(function(e) {
    $('.custom_ads_placement').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom_ads_placement" style="z-index:10000;">
  <div class="custom_closebtn">Close Ad</div>
  <div class="custom_adContent" style="z-index:12000;">
    <iframe src="http://exampledomain.com/ad.php" width="330" height="400" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" >Your Browser Do not Support Iframe</iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you wan't to remove it's code or just hide it ?

Comment: could you post some html

Comment: @MehdiBouzidi remove or hide doesn't matter

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn do you want me to update my question and put html code here instead of Jsfiddle link?

Comment: Is the jsfiddle the code that you are using?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn yes the same I am using but instead of `<img>` tag it will have `<iframe>` or `<script>` tag

Comment: Please post the code that isn't working..

Comment: You cannot remove/modify elements in the iframe's parent from the iframe unless they are both on the same domain.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn is there any solution that detects the click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make the code work correctly, however .remove() in jquery is not fully supported by all browsers See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove
You might consider a different strategy.

Here is an updated answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.custom_adContent').click(function(e) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('custom_adContent')[0].innerHTML="";
  });

   $('.custom_closebtn').click(function() {

    document.getElementsByClassName('custom_ads_placement')[0].innerHTML="";
  });
});
```

Comment: should I use hide() in this case?

Comment: even its not hiding when used hide() function can you show me the working example

Comment: Or you could use straight javascript to hide the class as in this example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aLKgEM

Comment: close button works but iframe won't hide when you click

Answer (score 2):

Your `img` is covering all the `custom_ads_placement` div so when you click on the div you're really clicking on the `img` & not on the div, you should use this selector: 
`.custom_ads_placement img`

This is the script you should implement:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
      $('.custom_closebtn').on('click',function() { 
    $('.custom_ads_placement').hide();

      });
        $('.custom_ads_placement img').on('click',function() { 
    $('.custom_ads_placement').hide();

      });
    });
```

and here is an update of your [IMAGE JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uvzjj9h4/4/) / [iFRAME JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uvzjj9h4/12/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as my image close properly on click but it won't close when I use `iframe` or `script` tags instead

Comment: just change the `img` to  `iframe` on the selector just like this `$('.custom_ads_placement iframe')` @Rtra

Comment: @Rtra give me the html containing the `iframe` please

Comment: here is an update to the `iframe` version https://jsfiddle.net/uvzjj9h4/10/

Comment: @Rtra note that I added an `id`  to the `iframe`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156502/discussion-between-mehdi-bouzidi-and-rtra).

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you have an iFrame with javascript in it that listens for a click on the iframe to close.

There is a few problem with this:

You can not modify the parent dom from an iframe. Browsers do not support this for security reasons.

To allow for cross origin communication You can use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) and send messages to the parent like so:

```
top.postMessage('close_iframe', '*')
```

This however requires that the parent window is listening for a message like so

```
window.addEventListener('message', e => {
    if(e.data == 'close_iframe') {
        // Delete/hide the add from here
    }
})
```

Your other (and possibly last) option would be to make a library and have the user add that, this library would then create the iframe and all the components related, this way it would be embedded in the page and all the JavaScript would be outside of the iframe.

Comment: None of the DOM he is accessing is in the iframe.  He can hide the thing containing the IFRAME just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove an iframe, simply cover it with a container

```
 <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%"></div>
```

Add style to parent

```
postion:relative
```

Then click works
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uvzjj9h4/9/)

The iframe happens because clicking is done on the child window, so you can do an action in an iframe like scrolling.

Comment: your code works for me but I won't be able to click on ad

Comment: Edit: position:relative

Comment: Thanks but I won't be able to click on the image